# Do 20mln of REST API calls using Azure Cloud infrastructure

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-durable-functions

There is a requirement to get the data, which is around 20 mln of entities, from the REST API, which does not have any rate limits and is insanely fast.

- Each entity has to be queried with two API calls - get metadata, then get the actual data.
- The size of the Entity vary from 1kb to 100Mb.
- Entities must be put to Blob Storage account in CSV format with any size of batches: 100 items in one file, or 1000 - does not matter for them.
- Azure Services must be used for this.
- The solution must run at least on 12-16 different API endpoints.
- would be nice for it to be completed in 1-2 days max.

Team tried the following:
(Note: using Premium Storage account, using Linux Premium v3 P3V3 app-plan)

1. Simple way

- Function App to issue 20 mln IDs to eventhub
  another function to listen for event hub and do these two calls + put to BLOB storage

Summary - takes ages even with scaled to 20 instances. Perhaps we are tweaking it wrong?

2. Durable Functions

- HttpTrigger that accepts the "signal" to kick off with a chunk size, this starts the Orchestration function
- Orchestration function calculates number of batches based on input batch size and issues N number of Sub orchestrations
- Each sub-orchestration triggers an Activity that does the API call and puts the data to Blob
- Durable Functions are backed up by MSSQL storage (16-vCore, Gen5 SQL Server instance)

Summary - runs few times faster then option 1, but SQL Server, often times out, perhaps skaling it to more cores would fix it... Also tried with Storage Account - few times slower.

3. Synapse pipelines.

- The pipeline with REST calls and ForEach cycles
- Without limits of execution
  Summary - takes ages for pipeline and costs a lot

These are all options we tried so far.

Ideally, it would be nice if it can perform this job in 1-2 days max. But now it takes several days with Option 2, based on Durable Functions.

**Dear community, please advise, perhaps there are any other services/tools to use to achieve this interesting goal?**

To clarify again: we must call REST API to get the data, it is not possible to access vendor's databases. The Database was mentioned ONLY as a storage for metadata for Azure Durable Functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think we found a way - create a simple Http-triggered function app in .NET that accepts a a definition of job - paging arguments: start index and number of items to fetch, inside it also splits the bulks of 100 calls per each and uses Parallel-call. It also writes inside to a Premium BLOB storage account.

Then designed a Synapse Pipeline that has an Until loop and accepts a number of batches to be called and inside it calls another pipeline.

The latter pipeline execute a function app supplying the batch details. For Until, removed "Wait for completion" and inside Foreach, removed "Sequenced".

The function must be in Consumption Plan (Y1).

It did that job in around 3hrs, which is amazing! Thanks, Azure!